# Get all value from array

Tags: php, arrays

I don't know How to get "name" value from all array ?

Any one please help me

I have some array like this

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Jon
                [phone] => 
                [relation] => wife
                [age] => 43
                [relative_education] => 4
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => John
                [phone] => 123456789
                [relation] => son
                [age] => 24
                [relative_education] => 10
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => Amy
                [phone] => 456789123
                [relation] => Son
                [age] => 21
                [relative_education] => 12
            )        
    )
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `array_column()`?

Comment: Do you want to create a separate array with names or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$name =  array_column($data, 'name');
print_r($name);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$names = array_map(function($user) {
    return $user['name'];
}, $users);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop the array to get the values.
If your array is $arr then use the below code to get the values

```
//$arr = YOUR ARRAY
$names = array();
foreach($arr as $val) {
        $names[] = $val['name'];
 }

print_r($names);
```